# Multi-account nodes in the EKS cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-eks, amazon-vpc

There is a need to attach instances from different third-part AWS accounts to the EKS cluster(for expenses reducing reasons) in our account. All delegation permissions for all third-part accounts could be provided. As an outcome, we have to get something like this

[image]

Is it feasible at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it feasible at all?

Nope. Your VPC lives in an account. And your subnets lives within your VPC, and you start your EC2 instances within any of those subnets. Also your EKS cluster is created within a single account.

Instead of creating *account A, account B* and *account C*, you could give those teams their own **namespace** within a centrally managed EKS cluster.